# Как оформить вопрос в предложении, если он не цитата?

Tags: пунктуация, вопрос

> Присутствуя на этой встрече, мы получим ответ на вопрос "Что делать во
> время карантина?".

Это оформление правильное?

Comment: Дубликаты встречаются редко. Выбор оформления зависит от структуры конкретного предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Такого рода предложения могут иметь **варианты оформления**.

1. *Присутствуя на этой встрече, мы получим ответ на вопрос **"Что делать во время карантина?».***

Дословное выражение заключается в кавычки и используется как структурный элемент предложения. Двоеточие не ставится, предупредительная пауза отсутствует. Такое оформление подходит для  сложных и осложненных предложений, когда паузу делать неудобно.

Розенталь,  § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора (примечание)
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

2. *Лектору  задали вопрос:  **"Что делать во время карантина?"***

Это обычное оформление прямой речи, где ставится двоеточие и делается пауза.